# Can I publish an app on tha Play Store that has almost the same nape that other app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Imagine that there is a popular app on Google Play that is named "Obtain results making abdominal exercise in 10 days - exercises of abdominals". Now my question is, could I publish my app with a similar name like "Obtain results making biceps exercise in 10 days - exercises of biceps". So only changing two words of the name of the pupular app. Is this permited on Google Play? Is it considered copy or copyright? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, if "Obtain results making abdominal exercise in 10 days - exercises of abdominals" rights are not reserved. Google just looking for package name, not app name. Of course, the app name can't be Facebook, Twitter :)